# React Redux toolkit createAsyncThunk doesnt give any return

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit's `createAsyncThunk` and `Axios` for async requests. At first, it works, but when I was doing sth with scss, the chrome gives me that `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`. I didn't change anything about redux and thunk but useSelector gets nothing. Also, the interface(it works) didn't give any response.

thunk and slice:

```
export const getTopBanners = createAsyncThunk(
    'home/getTopBanners',
    async ()=>{
        console.log('hello?');
        const response = await axiosGetTopBanner();
        console.log('res:'+response);
        return response.banners
    }
)

export const topBannerSlice = createSlice({
    name:'topBanner',
    initialState:{
        pics:[],
        isLoading:false
    },
    extraReducers:{
        [getTopBanners.pending]:(state)=>{
            state.isLoading = true;
        },
        [getTopBanners.fulfilled]:(state,action)=>{
            state.pics = action.payload;
            state.isLoading = false;
        },
        [getTopBanners.rejected]:(state)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
        }
    }
})
```

component:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
//gets nothing here
const topBanners = useSelector((state) => state.topBanner.pics);
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTopBanners());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

store:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer:{
    topBanner:topBannerReducer,
    recommendData:recommendDataReducer
  }
})
```

Comment: I think axios returns the data of the response at `data`. Try: `return response.data.banners` or just `return response.data`

Comment: hi bro, thanks for ur help but it still doesn't work. I have tested the interface in another JS file. It gives me [OK]xxx/xxx in PowerShell. But PowerShell shows nothing here with `await axiosGetTopBanner();`. So, I'm wondering if maybe this function doesn't fetch anything?

Comment: Maybe you can show your `axiosGetTopBanner` function

Comment: `export const axiosGetTopBanner = () => {
    return instance.get("/banner");
};`   and I tried to use this function in app.js directly, It works.

Comment: Since you're logging the response, is it what you're expecting it to be?

Answer (score 0):

```js
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getTopBanners.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.pics = action.payload; 
      });
}
```